# PDF metadata from translations \GetTranslation produces incorrect chararcter encoding?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, input-encodings, translations

While coding my own class I use `\GetTranslation` from the `translations` package to allow using different languages and `\hypersetup` from `hyperref` to set PDF metadata.

If I use `\GetTranslation` in the document, utf8 special characters are encoded correctly. However if I use `\GetTranslation` for PDF metadata, utf8 special characters appear as incorrectly interpreted as ISO 8859-1 characters, e.g. `Ã¤` instead of `ä`. If I directly use utf8 special characters for PDF metadata, they are correctly encoded.

The following MWE produces *Töst or Täst* in the document but  *Töst or TÃ¤st* in the PDF title.

Why is that and how can I fix it so that special characters from `\GetTranslation` are correctly encoded in PDF metadata?

Using `\"a` instead of `ä` in `\NewTranslation` produces a warning (“Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode), removing \" ”) and *Töst or Tast* remains as the PDF title.

---

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{translations}
\DeclareTranslationFallback{test}{Test}
\NewTranslation{ngerman}{test}{Täst}

\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,psdextra,pdftex]{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \hypersetup{
    pdftitle = {\mytitle}
  }
}

\newcommand{\mytitle}{Töst or \GetTranslation{test}}

\begin{document}
  \mytitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try the `unicode` option of `hyperref` package?

Comment: @PaulGaborit does not seem to work, the pdf meta seems to see the ä as two chars.

Comment: Yes, adding the `unicode` option does not change anything in the output (as far as I can see)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the translations package surrounds the output by a `\unexpanded` and this stops the hyperref processing:

```
\newcommand*\@trnslt@translation@value[2]{%
  \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \csname @trnslt@word@\detokenize{#1}@#2\endcsname
  }%
}
```

You can try an variant of the `\GetTranslation` that avoid this (I'm not quite sure if I got the language part right, it could perhaps fails for unknown translations). If the text of the translation contains fragile commands you will perhaps to use `\texorpdfstring` if you use it in section titles:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{translations}
\DeclareTranslationFallback{test}{Test}
\NewTranslation{ngerman}{test}{Täst}

\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,psdextra]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\GetTranslationPDF[1]{%
 \csname @trnslt@word@\detokenize{#1}@\@trnslt@language{\@trnslt@current@language}\endcsname
 }
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{
  \hypersetup{
    pdftitle = {\mytitle}
  }
}

\newcommand{\mytitle}{\GetTranslationPDF{test}}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \section{\GetTranslationPDF{test}}

\end{document}
```

### Edit

the following could work als for language without translation. But it would be better to make a feature request to the package author

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{translations}

\DeclareTranslationFallback{test}{Test}
\NewTranslation{ngerman}{test}{Täst}

\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,psdextra,pdftex]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@trnslt@checkandget@translation@forPDF[2]{%
  \@trnslt@if@translation{#1}{#2}
    {\@trnslt@get@translation@forPDF{#1}{#2}}
    {%
      \@trnslt@if@translation{#1}{fallback}
        {\@trnslt@translation@valuePDF{#1}{fallback}}
        {\@trnslt@translation@valuePDF{#1}{literal}}%
    }%
}

\newcommand*\@trnslt@get@translation@forPDF[2]{%
  \@trnslt@if@dialect{#2}
    {%
      \@trnslt@if@translation@valuePDF{#1}{\@trnslt@dialect{#2}}
        {\@trnslt@translation@valuePDF{#1}{\@trnslt@dialect{#2}}}
        {\@trnslt@translation@valuePDF{#1}{\@trnslt@dialect@of{#2}}}%
    }
    {\@trnslt@translation@valuePDF{#1}{\@trnslt@language{#2}}}%
}
\newcommand*\@trnslt@translation@valuePDF[2]{%
    \csname @trnslt@word@\detokenize{#1}@#2\endcsname
}

\newcommand*\GetTranslationPDF[1]{%
  \@trnslt@checkandget@translation@forPDF{#1}{\@trnslt@current@language}}

\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{
  \hypersetup{
    pdftitle = {\mytitle}
  }
}

\newcommand{\mytitle}{\GetTranslationPDF{test}}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \section{\GetTranslationPDF{test}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! Your solution appears to work as long as there is an explicit translation. Unfortunately `\GetTranslationPDF` produces no output (neither in the document nor in the PDF metadata) if the default translation is used (e.g. by requiring `french` without let’s say `\NewTranslation{french}{test}{Tèst}`), because `hyperref` removes the result (“Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): (hyperref) removing \@trnslt@word@test@french' ”) and `\@trnslt@word@test@french` is empty

Comment: As I said, I haven't really looked at the language part. The best would be to make a feature request so that the package adds a version without the unexpanded.

Comment: Sure, and it isn’t a problem if the `\csname … \endcsname` is wrapped with `\@trnslt@if@translation` and you require `fallback` or `literal` otherwise. Which leads me to the question why there is an `\unexpanded` in the first place? In what situations would you need it?

Comment: Can you make an example where it fails so that I can test another code?#

Comment: I added an edit - perhaps it works.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was trying to describe! I'm still wondering why there is an `\unexpanded` in the package? What does it do? (“What are we breaking by removing it?”)